# Make a change to the database with Prisma.js without having to reset the whole thing

Tags: node.js, prisma, prisma2

How can make a change to the database with `Prisma.js` without having to reset the whole thing?

if I have used this command

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name role-makeOptional-NormalizedName
```

I will lose all of the data in my database but I don't lose my data.

In my case I wanted to change `String` to `String?` in `schema.prisma` file

```
NormalizedName  String?            @unique @db.VarChar(64)
```

Is there a proper command to avoid losing the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go into your schema and make the change:

```
NormalizedName  String            @unique @db.VarChar(64)
NormalizedName  String?            @unique @db.VarChar(64)
```

Then create a draft migration:

```
$ npx prisma migrate dev --name migration-name --create-only
```

Then edit the migration in SQL (this allow null values ie optional)

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN myColumn {DataType} NULL;
```

OR Postgres

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN myColumn DROP NOT NULL;
```

etc.

Then apply the modified SQL:

```
$ npx prisma migrate dev
```

I hope this works for you :)

Comment: **NOTE:** `--create-only` doesn't prevent data loss when Prisma detects a drift. It **"should"** _(at least the name implies that it "should")_ prevent data loss but doesn't; in my experience it drops all tables except `_prisma_migrations` and then just doesn't re-create the tables.  Not sure why Prisma prioritizes complete data loss.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Again prisma warns me that data will be lost.

Comment: data will still be lost

Comment: Why did you approved this answer? This isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

In a development environment, Prisma Migrate sometimes prompts you to reset the database. Resetting drops and recreates the database, which results in data loss. The database is reset when:

- You call `prisma migrate reset` explicitly
- You call `prisma migrate dev` and Prisma Migrate detects drift in the database or a migration history conflict

I'm not sure why Prisma thinks that your change is breaking, but there is probably no other way to make schema change without data loss.

To recreate your database data consider using [seeding script](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/seed-database)

If you are prototyping, consider using the [`db push` command](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/db-push), although it will still result in data reset if Prisma considers that the change is breaking.

Comment: If you create your database with `db push` or for some other reason have no migrations table in your db then prisma will want to reset it every time.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. What happened was that an error occurred during one of my migrations and because of that it puts prisma into an error state. Prisma doesn't want to run any new migrations while in this error state.

To solve it:

- Removed the broken migration folder that was auto generated inside /prisma/migrations
- Remove the broken row that is created inside the _prisma_migrations table in your database

Answer (score 0):

*I had this issue when the migration was slightly modified, like the formatting, the spacing got different.*

#### Force a broken migration to be treated as applied

1. Find your migration in the DB `_prisma_migrations` table and remove its row
2. Run `npx prisma migrate resolve --applied MIGRATION_NAME`